# Return a Formatted String in Rust

Tags: string, rust, formatting, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'd like to create a function that takes an `x` and `y` coordinate values and returns a string of the format `(x,y)`:

```rust
pub struct Coord {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let my_coord = Coord {
        x: 10,
        y: 12
    };

    let my_string = coords(my_coord.x, my_coord.y);

    fn coords(x: i32, y: i32) -> &str{
        let l = vec!["(", x.to_string(), ",", y.to_string(), ")"];
        let j = l.join("");
        println!("{}", j);
        return &j
    }
}
```

This gives me the error:

```
   |
14 |     fn coords(x: i32, y: i32) -> &str {
   |                                  ^ expected named lifetime parameter
   |
   = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value with an elided lifetime, but the lifetime cannot be derived from the arguments
help: consider using the `'static` lifetime
   |
```

Adding the `'static` lifetime seems to cause a host of other problems with this function? How can I fix this?

Comment: Return a String.

Comment: There is useful `format!` macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The more idiomatic approach would be to implement the `Display` trait for your type `Coord` which would allow you to call `to_string()` on it directly, and also would allow you to use it in the `println!` macro directly. Example:

```rust
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter, Result};

pub struct Coord {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Display for Coord {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> Result {
        write!(f, "({}, {})", self.x, self.y)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_coord = Coord { x: 10, y: 12 };
    
    // create string by calling to_string()
    let my_string = my_coord.to_string();
    println!("{}", my_string); // prints "(10, 12)"
    
    // can now also directly pass to println! macro
    println!("{}", my_coord); // prints "(10, 12)"
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7b96cc5ac3a84e6f5a255e877fb1d40f)

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is not possible. The `String` you are creating is local to the function and you are trying to return a reference to it.

`j` will be dropped at the end of the function, so you can't return a reference to it.

You will have to return a `String`:

```rust
fn coords(x: i32, y: i32) -> String {
    let l = vec![
        "(".into(),
        x.to_string(),
        ",".into(),
        y.to_string(),
        ")".into(),
    ];
    let j = l.join("");
    println!("{}", j);
    return j;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bb6e944caa3c26ad28fc38a342ab017f)

---

A better way to do the same:

```rust
fn coords(x: i32, y: i32) -> String {
    let x = format!("({},{})", x, y);
    println!("{}", x);
    return x;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1ae3a514e6e384918b74b21f50079b65)

Answer (score 0):

this ended up working for me:

```rust
pub struct Coord{
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

fn main(){
    let my_coord = Coord{
        x: 10,
        y: 12
    };

    let my_string = coords(my_coord.x, my_coord.y);

    fn coords(x: i32, y: i32) -> String{
        let myx = x.to_string(); 
        let myy = y.to_string(); 
        let l = vec!["(", &myx, ",", &myy, ")"];
        let j = l.join("");
        return j; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You can just return `format!("({}, {})", x, y)` which is simpler, more readable, and more efficient to boot.